# Java String Initialization and Default Value

Tags: java, string

Is it correct to initialize a String as

```
String value = new String("test");
```

value of string is assigned in multiple places and if value is null, then default value which is test should be taken, which means if I declare

```
String value = null;
```

at some point I have assign a value if in code no value is assigned.

Comment: It's correct, but is a waste of resources. Just use `String value = "test";` I don't understand what you mean with the second part of the question.

Comment: I don't understood the second part of your question.

Comment: Are you trying to dodge a NullPointer ?

Comment: It is better to check for a null instead. `if(str != null && your conditions)`

Comment: are you asking `if value is assigned null, then you want to change it to "test" by default`?

Comment: @UmaKanth So it is better to check string is null or not rather than assigning a default value?

Comment: Do you mean that you does not control what would be in the string and you don't want it to be null?

Comment: Default value concept as you are asking is not there in Java - you may want to write a convenience method like `getValue()` and return `test` if value is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables can't have a default value that is used if you assign them later to null. That doesn't exist.

If you do

```
String a = "test"; 
// ...
a = null;
```

then `a` will have the value `null`. If you want to use "test" instead of null, then you have to do it explicitely:

```
String actualValue = a;
if (actualValue == null) {
    actualValue = "test";
}
```

or simply

```
String actualValue = a == null ? "test" : a;
```

Comment: My intention is to avoid using if condition to check string value is null or not by assigning a default value.

Comment: But there is no such thing as a default value for a variable. That's my point. If you assign "test" to a a variable, and some code reassigns it to null later, it will become null.

Comment: That is fine, at declaration time string is test and if no values are assigned then test value will be taken correct?

Comment: Well, yes, if you assign the value "test" to a variable, its value will be "test". That's what an assignment does.

Comment: So `String value = "test"` is declared and test will be it's value if no other assignment is done to variable during execution of the code correct?

Comment: @user75ponic yes, unless you are talking about multi threaded program.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 5):

I  think you won't be able to change `value = null` to `value= "test"` by default. If the string "test" is really important to you, when you are accessing `value`, do this:

```
  if(value == null){
      value = "test";
  }
```

Instead of writing this condition everywhere in the code, what you can do is call a function `getStringValue()` instead of using `value`.

```
 String getStringValue(){
    if(value == null){ 
       value = "test"
    }
    return value;
 }
```

This is same as checking the condition as mentioned above but this produces cleaner code and you don't need to write that condition every time.

Comment: Thanks Karthik for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string not to be null, you can simply check the value before assigning it.

```
String value = valueCommingFromSomewhere;
if (value == null) {
    value = "myDefaultValue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.